# Google Map Markers Linking to Same Page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create a Google Map in which each marker links to a different page (using Ruby on Rails, Google Maps API 3). My code for the markers:

```
var mapSpots = [
  <% @spots.each do |spot| %>
    ['<%= spot.name %>', <%= spot.lat %>, <%= spot.lng %>, '<%= spot_path(spot) %>'],
  <% end %>
];

for (var i = 0; i < mapSpots.length; i++) {
  var mapSpot = mapSpots[i];
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: mapSpot[1], lng: mapSpot[2]},
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    title: mapSpot[0]
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    window.location.href = mapSpot[3];
  });
}
```

Markers are created for each entry in the "Spot" model. Problem is, the markers all link to the *same* page—oddly enough, to spot with id: 2 (I currently have 3 spot entries). Any thoughts on how to ensure that each marker links to the appropriate spot path?

Perhaps embedded ruby isn't the best way to do this?

Comment: maybe it's something bad with your @spots variable, check your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mapSpots = [
  <% @spots.each do |spot| %>
    ['<%= spot.name %>', <%= spot.lat %>, <%= spot.lng %>, '<%= spot_path(spot) %>'],
  <% end %>
];

for (var i = 0; i < mapSpots.length; i++) {
  (function(n) {
    var mapSpot = mapSpots[n];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: mapSpot[1], lng: mapSpot[2]},
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      title: mapSpot[0]
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
      window.location.href = mapSpot[3];
    });
  })(i);
}
```

I think this is the most common bug among javascript developers. When you create a callback like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
  window.location.href = mapSpot[3];
});
```

You actually create a closure which holds reference to mapSpot variable and all your callback functions hold reference to the same mapSpot variable. Since you modify this variable in every loop iteration, after last iteration it's value will be the value of the last marker.

You added `var mapSpot` at the beginning of loop, but it is not creating new variable in every loop iteration. There is no loop scope in javascript,  only function scope. Your mapSpot definition is actually hoisted outside of the loop. It looks more like this:

var mapSpot;

```
for (var i = 0; i < mapSpots.length; i++) {
  mapSpot = mapSpots[i];
  ...
```

Comment: Worked like a charm—thanks! As your solution and as @Matej P. pointed out, I ought to spend some time better understanding closures. Again, thanks for your help.